# Returning options from mapping over values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey everyone so I am making a get request to a google API and pulling in some data. Initially, my state value is just an empty object and from the ajax request I am expecting the state values to be filled with `setState`.

Then, in another method I am taking that state data and mapping over the items and returning an option for each element within that array. The weird thing is that right before I start returning the values that I am mapping over I am console.loging the values and they are exactly the values that I want. However, when I return an option with that value inside there is still nothing inside my select.

Can anyone please elaborate what I could be possibly doing incorrectly?

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  };

componentDidMount() {
  let URL = is the url with my api key (it works)
  axios.get(URL)
  .then((data) => {
      console.log("data" + data);
      this.setState({
        googleFonts: data
      })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.setState({
      errors: err
    })
  })
}

renderFonts() {
  let data = this.state.googleFonts.data.items;
  return data.map((font, index) => {
    console.log(font.family);
    return (
     <ul>
       <li>{font.family}</li>
      </ul>
    )
  })
}

<FormControl
    style={inputFieldStyle}
    componentClass="select"
    placeholder="select" >
  {setTimeout(this.renderFonts, 100)}
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Please format your code. You current example doesn't even have a render method

Comment: Well there is just so much code I can post inside before its too much code I can assure you its inside a render method I am just showing you as much context as possible

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout`? What if the request doesn't finish in 100ms?

Comment: @PeternDev are you getting any error in console? also if you want to render the options then use `<option value={font.family}>{font.family}</option>` instead of `ul`.

Comment: @Li357 my reason for using setTimeout is because the ajax call is called with componentDidMount so if I just called the method without setTimeout then the data is still undefined.

Comment: @MayankShukla thank you for your response I have tried that and no luck my select value is still no values from my state data

Comment: @PeternDev Exactly my point. Not good to set a hardcoded timeout - what if the request doesn't finish? Just check if the data exists in the render method

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
//after `render()`
const data = this.state.googleFonts.data.items

return (
  <FormControl
   style={inputFieldStyle}
   componentClass="select"
   placeholder="select"
  >
    {data && data.map((font, index) => 
        <option>{font.family}</option>
     )}
  </FormControl>
```

I believe that's how React-Bootstrap is expecting it to be written, and it's a little less code. Using the logical `&&` operator allows it to populate the dropdown after the state loads.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

First: `{setTimeout(this.renderFonts, 100)}` returns `timeoutID` is a positive integer value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setTimeout()`  and hence although renderFonts is executed nothing is returned from it to be rendered

Second: `componentDidMount` is called after render and you have your API request in componentDidMount, so delaying the value to be rendered by using a setTimeout is a horrible idea, since you are never sure as to when you would get a response from the API, for a slow network it could take a really long time and hence even after a timeout of 100ms, you may still not have the data and so `this.state.googleFonts.data.items` might still be undefined or the response may come within 10ms in which case you are unnecessarily delaying the render.

```
A better way to solve this is to have provide a check for the presence of data.
```

You could do it like

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  };

componentDidMount() {
  let URL = is the url with my api key (it works)
  axios.get(URL)
  .then((data) => {
      console.log("data" + data);
      this.setState({
        googleFonts: data
      })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.setState({
      errors: err
    })
  })
}

renderFonts() {
  let data = this.state.googleFonts? this.state.googleFonts.data.items: [];
  return data.map((font, index) => {
    console.log(font.family);
    return (
     <ul>
       <li>{font.family}</li>
      </ul>
    )
  })
}

<FormControl
    style={inputFieldStyle}
    componentClass="select"
    placeholder="select" >
  {this.renderFonts()}
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. It's more to do with how you have structured your code and callback. Take a look at this sample -

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'there',
      title: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let URL = 'https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Books'
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: URL,
      responseType: 'json'
    })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data);
        this.setState({
          title: data.data[0].Title
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({
          errors: err
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component-app">
        <h1>Hello {this.state.name}! {'\u2728'}</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

I have coded it here. Have a look

[image: Edit l2j0rx5qxm]

Instead of `componentDidMount` you can use `componentWillMount`. Also you would be seeing errors in console with your code somthing like `React - setState() on unmounted component`. If you fix that you should be able to get your code working.